# Modern preloading when navigating page to page with jquery

Tags: jquery, preloader, preload

I've searched other posts but haven't found what I'm looking for. I wanted to find out how to preload a new page when navigating section by section. I've seen this on http://www.mixcloud.com

When you navigate section by section (once logged in) it will have a loader scroll across the top then push you to the new page once it has been completed. Is this custom or an open source thing?

YouTube is also using the same thing now http://www.youtube.com

Comment: i wouldn't call it pre-loading, as all of the loading is done on demand. history.js might help you get started with adding this type of functionality. Essentially you're intercepting what would normally cause a page refresh and instead retrieving the content with ajax.

Answer (score 0):

NProgress is one  open source project that facilitates loading state and progress state if you're trying to achieve what Google and MixCloud are doing.

http://ricostacruz.com/nprogress/

Keep in mind though these sites are taking advantage of push state + AJAX calls to collect more data on the status which would help control components like page loading. Think SPA-like sites to implement this kind of feature.

Answer (score 0):

What you looking for is called ajax and pushState, Ajax load new content of the page whitout any refresh while pushState change the Url.

There is some jQuery plugins can play this role, try using [NProgress](https://github.com/rstacruz/nprogress/) whit [Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks)